# Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибки.(я новичок) Мне нужно получить cos x/(pi-2x)+16*x*cos(x*y)-2. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Tags: ассемблер

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter x and y" << endl;
    double pi = 3.1415;
    double x, u;
    cin >> x;
    x = fabs(x);
    x / pi;
    if ((x < 0) || (x > 2 * pi))
    {
        while (x < 0 || x > 2 * pi)
        {
            if (x < 0) x += 2 * pi;
            if (x > 2 * pi) x -= 2 * pi;
        }
    }
    int z, n, m, p, h, k, y, p1, p2;
    double s, g;
    cin >> y;
    if ((x*y < 0) || (x*y > 2 * pi))
    {
        u = x * y;
        while (x*y < 0 || x * y>2 * pi)
        {
            if (u < 0)
                u = u + 2 * pi;
            if (u > 2 * pi)
                u = u + 2 * pi;
        }
    }
    while (fabs(p) > 0, 000000001)
    {
        p = p * x * x / n * (n + 1);
        s = s + p;
        n = n + 2;
    }
    while (fabs(p) > 0,000000001)
    {
        p = p * x*y * x*y / n * (n + 1);
        g = g + p;
        n = n + 2;
    }
    g *= 1000;
    s *= 1000;
    g /= 10;
    s /= 10;
    pi *= 1000;
    pi /= 10;
    _asm
    {
        mov ebx, pi
        mov ecx, 2
        imul ecx, x
        sub ebx, ecx
        mov eax, s
        div ebx
        mov p1, eax
        mov eax, g
        mul x
        mul k
        mov p2, eax
        mov ebx, 2
        mov ecx, p1
        add ecx, p2
        sub ecx, ebx
        mov z, ecx
    }
    cout << z;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Отредактируйте ваш вопрос. Не нужно пытаться в название запихнуть всё. Также напишите в чём проявляются ошибки.

Comment: В основном в ассемблере в 1, 5 и 8 строчках. Также в конце он ничего не выводит.

Comment: А мне нужно написать функцию указанную выше

Comment: Нельзя в целочисленные регистры класть вещественные числа. В Win32 для этого есть регистры FPU, организованные в стек

Comment: @MBo, они не в Win32, они в процессоре, доступны и из 16 битного режима тоже.

Comment: @insolor Видимо, я неудачную формулировку использовал, имея в виду, что код, скорее всего, относится к  32-x разрядным ( а не x64) компиляторам